# launching an iPhone/iPad standalone app from another iPhone/iPad standalone app possible?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Is it possible to launch a standalone iPhone application from another standalone iPhone app(may be on click of a button or something...)?

Answer (score 1):

[chech this](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes)  most app's url scheme

you can use url scheme to open another app ,even send parameters to the app

ex: open safari

```
NSString *stringURL = @"http://www.gogole.com/";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```